# Fix TypeError: matchesSelector is not a function in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, masonry

I'm trying to use `masonry-layout` from [here](https://masonry.desandro.com/#install), to create a masonry grid in my component. However, I am running into the issue that clicking an element rendered by the component is returning the error `TypeError: matchesSelector is not a function`. I moved the masonry functionality to the component and wrapped it in a `useEffect`, which seemed to fix other rendering issue, but now it says that it can't trigger the functionality on click.

I was thinking I may need to use `useRef` on the grid, but not sure of the implementation here.

I'm able to get most of the functionality I want from working with it in plain JS in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u196wvj2/), but trying to translate it to a React component.

```
    import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
    import Masonry from 'masonry-layout';

    const Grid = items => {
        useEffect(() => {
        const grid = document.querySelector('.grid');
        const masonry = new Masonry(grid);
        let previouslyEnlarged;
        let matchesSelector = () => {};
        grid.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            if (!matchesSelector(event.target, '.grid-item')) {
                return;
            }

            if (previouslyEnlarged === event.target) {
                return;
            } else if (previouslyEnlarged) {
                previouslyEnlarged.classList.remove('grid-item--gigante');
            }

            previouslyEnlarged = event.target;

            event.target.classList.toggle('grid-item--gigante');
            masonry.layout();
        });
    });
    return (
        <div>
            <div class="grid">
                <div class="grid-holder">{items.map((item, i) => <div class="grid-item">{item.name}</div>)}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Grid;
```

Comment: You declare matchesSelector with let matchesSelector; but does not initialize it to anything so it is undefined. Then when you try to call it it gives the error because it is undefined. In your fiddle it looks like it is a global object because it is not declared inside your code so try to remove the line where you declare matchesSelector.

Answer (score 0):

So the trick to enable access to each grid item and click it was to use a hook to set the state and toggle a class:

```
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState(null);
    const expandItem = e => {
        const index = parseInt(e.target.getAttribute('data-index'));
        setSelected(index);
    };

                

    <div className={`grid-item ${selected === i && 'grid-item--gigante'}`}
        onClick={expandItem}
        data-index={i}>item data</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

`let matchesSelector;` is undefined. if you want it to be a function you have to initialize it. something like:

`let matchesSelector = () => { ... };`

Comment: I updated my code (and the example above), but it’s still not triggering the divs on click.

Comment: He is obviously trying to use a library method and not trying to implement matchesSelector function.

Comment: What am I missing that I'm able to trigger the click on each element that's being mapped over for the masonry in the fiddle, but it's not triggering in my react component?